# Ionic Material 2 images in row

Tags: ionic-framework, material-design, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on Ionic Material and I want 2 images in a row like Ionic material Demo app.It is showing only 1 now in a row. I created a  **https://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/jVqvaV** 
From It,So Need Help to fix this issue.

Now That issue has fixed and image is showing but main issue is tomaintain size,check updated pen on same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code pen  codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/jVqvaV
I used col50 and some css then i fixed it .

Answer (score 0):

Look at this solution:

```js
/*global angular*/

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic-material', 'ionMdInput'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: '/event',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/event-menu.html'
    })
  .state('eventmenu.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller: 'GalleryCtrl'
        }
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/event/login');
})
.directive('ngLastRepeat', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngLastRepeat'+ (attr.ngLastRepeat ? '.'+attr.ngLastRepeat : ''));
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function(){
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
      ionicMaterialMotion.ripple();
  },0);
})

.controller('GalleryCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion) {
    console.log("in GalleryCtrl");
    // Activate ink for controller
    //ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();

    $scope.myPics= [{
    "Title": "My Childhood",
    "Like": "21",
    "Comment" : "5",
    "Image" : "http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/lovely-child-blue-eyes-photo-wallpaper-2560x1600-1-694x417.jpg"
  },{
    "Title": "Funny me",
    "Like": "21",
    "Comment" : "5",
    "Image" : "http://media.salemwebnetwork.com/cms/CW/family/2218-ChildLookUp.220w.tn.jpg"
  },{
    "Title": "Me",
    "Like": "21",
    "Comment" : "5",
    "Image" : "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QDe-qthaKz0/UAWZ6aakdoI/AAAAAAAAFK4/2zlaIu1r20Q/s1600/baby.jpg"
  },{
    "Title": "Guitar",
    "Like": "21",
    "Comment" : "5",
    "Image" : "http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/800-1280/shopping/pixs/17369/c/caihd224_1._craft-art-india-handmade-dummy-miniature-of-guitar-gitar-code-cai-hd-0224-.jpg"
  }];
$scope.$on('ngLastRepeat.mylist',function(e) {
    console.log("in Last ");
     ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
});
});
/*endglobal angular*/
```

```css
/* General
==================================*/
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px #000;
    font-size: 42px;
}


/* Utilities
==================================*/
.title-bordered {
    border-top: solid 2px #bbb;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

p {
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.scroll {
    height: 100%;
}


/* Menu
==================================*/
.menu .bar.bar-header.expanded {
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-open .bar.bar-header.expanded {
    background-color: #222;
}

.menu h2 {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 16px;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu .avatar {
    height: 88px;
    width: 88px;
}

.menu.menu-left * {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-open .ion-navicon {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-open .ion-navicon:before {
    content: "\f2ca";
}


/* Login
==================================*/
.app-icon {
    background-color: #fff;
    background: url('../img/login.PNG') center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 125px;
}

.social-login {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

.error{
    padding: 4px 1px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.red_bg{
    color:red;
}
.yellow_bg{
    background-color: #eae07f!important;
}


.gallery-box .card.card-gallery img {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height: 132px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Material </title>

      <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/demo/www/lib/ion-md-input/css/ion-md-input.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
         <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/demo/www/lib/ion-md-input/js/ion-md-input.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
    <script id="templates/event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ul class="list animate-rip">
              <!-- Note each link has the 'menu-close' attribute so the menu auto closes when clicking on one of these links -->
              <a href="#/event/login" class="item" menu-close>Gallery</a>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
      </ion-side-menus>
    </script>
     <script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Gallery" class="gallery-box">
    <ion-content ng-class="{expanded:isExpanded}" class="animate-fade-slide-in">
     <div class="list col" >
            <div  class="item card card-gallery item-text-wrap in demo" ng-repeat="picsItem in myPics" >
                      
                <div class="ink dark-bg">
                    <h2>{{picsItem.Title}}</h2>
                    <img ng-src="{{picsItem.Image}}" class="full-image" ng-last-repeat="mylist">
                </div>
                <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left in demo">
                    <a class="tab-item stable-bg assertive">
                        <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
                        {{picsItem.Like}}
                    </a>
                    <a class="tab-item stable-bg positive-900">
                        <i class="icon ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        {{picsItem.Comment}}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```